# Depth of a decision tree

Tags: classification, cart

Since the decision tree algorithm split on an attribute at every step, the maximum depth of a decision tree is equal to the number of attributes of the data.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 28):

No, because the data can be split on the same attribute multiple times. And this characteristic of decision trees is important because it allows them to capture nonlinearities in individual attributes.

Edit: In support of the point above, here's the first regression tree I created. Note that volatile acidity and alcohol appear multiple times:

[image]

Comment: @mkt if you feel like editing again you can add that typically a decision tree stops creating new branches when wither  a pre-specified purity level is reached, a node has less than a specified number of elements, or a split of a node would lead to a new node with less than a specified number of elements.  These reasons can easily lead to an attribute not being used at all.

Comment: +1, but this plot does leave something to be desired. Which branch represents `yes`, eg? It might help to post the dataset & code, if that's doable.

Comment: @aginensky Thanks, those are worthwhile points! But I don't think I know enough about decision tree stopping criteria to do it justice here. Perhaps it would be worth your adding an additional answer?

Comment: @gung This is a regression tree, so there's no yes/no branching. I will try to dig up the code and data and post.

Comment: What I mean is, suppose `alcohol = 10.50` (ie, `alcohol < 10.53`), do you then proceed down the right or left branch of the tree?

Comment: Nice answer! Can you clarify what your outcome variable was for the decision tree you built and also if there were any other attributes that did not turn out to be important and don't feature in your plot?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement how is that relevant to the question that was asked? It seems like it would just distract from the main point.

Comment: Right, it's not clear in your example that the given branches are mutually exclusive. Like if I have a sulphate of 0.64 and it has volatile acidity of 1.02 and alcohol is 9, which branch would I take? Even if the tree isn't a pure binary yes/no, each sub-branch at a given point needs to be distinct from the other branches at that point in order to move forward.

Comment: Well, if it's not relevant, just ignore the question.  I already deleted my answer to this question as it was deemed by @gung to be a comment rather than an answer. i am not getting user-friendly vibes from this thread so will be moving on to threads where I feel lke my contributions are more welcomed.

Comment: Also the point where you split at alcohol < 11.55 is invalid because that is always going to be true since alcohol must be < 10.53 to reach that point. (Which is relevant because fixing it changes the max depth, so that your point is not as well demonstrated)

Comment: @mkt  All software I've seen has parameters with default values for them.  I don't know of any theory that fits minimums.  I must admit that it's been a while since I used either decision trees or regression trees.  My recollection is that once a tree is fit, it is pruned for optimal predictive power.  This makes it unnecessary to 'fine tune' the exact stopping points, at least imho.

Comment: @gung Got it, good point. Will edit with an updated plot soon.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement Thanks! The outcome was 'wine quality' (rating by experts) and yes, there were several attributes that were found to be unimportant.

Comment: @Anthony That is the 'no' branch i.e. where alcohol is >10.53. So the split is valid. Your point also addresses gung's question.

Comment: @aginensky My understanding is that there is a great deal of debate/development around stopping criteria and methods to limit overfitting (such as pruning). I will see if I can address this better when updating the answer later.

Comment: @mkt  I would be surprised if there is that much discussion about that topic.  Simply,  RF and gradient boosting typically provide much better answers.  I would be very curious to know of a problem for which trees with any stopping criteria outperform (in prediction) either of those two methods.  Let me know if you have a good example of that- it would be very interesting.

Comment: @aginensky I'm not arguing that they outperforming bagging/boosting solutions; merely that in the literature I read a while ago, there appeared to be scope for greater optimisation around the stopping criteria (which are relevant for RFs & GBMs as well).

Answer (score 0):

Well if the features are categorical this above regression answer doesn't really hold true. Then it is dependent on the number of categories how many splits you can do on one feature. If each feature only has two categories, then OP would be correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/344950)